# SailsJs/Express removing nested array `res.send()`

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js

I'm using [SailsJs](http://sailsjs.org/) (which is Express based) to send an JSON object with an array. For some reason, when I load the API in my browser, the array is not sent.

The **code that sends the object** is here:

```
exports.RESTifySend = function(res, objects) {
    return RESTService.RESTify(objects).then(function(RESTedObjects) {
        console.log("SENDING: ", RESTedObjects);
        return res.json(RESTedObjects, 200); // I've also tried res.send()
    }, function() {
        res.send(500);
    });
};
```

The **logging statement** `SENDING: ...` outputs:

```
SENDING: {
    id: 'IKIlrgXhp6',
    messages: [{
        user: null, 
        text: 'trest', 
        sentAt: undefined 
    }]
}
```

The `RESTifyService` is just a small framework I built to remove object attributes that shouldn't be exposed in the API (passwords, emails, etc.).

Comment: Can you show how you are actually using `RESTifySend` in your controller code?  The problem may be in your invocation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in the framework I built, I replaced `toObject();` with `lodash.clone([object])`, which solved all the problems. For others experiencing a similar issue, I suggest trying the same thing in your `toJSON` method. The `toObject();` method of waterline objects apparently has some odd side effects when you true to populate or edit an attribute that matches the name of an association.

Answer (score 0):

Also ran into this issue when serializing a model with a collection attribute (like something with many `Comments`).

In my case I call .toJSON on the record object with the collection during serialization, which has a model definition like:

```
attributes: {
  ...
  toJSON: function() {
    var self = this.toObject()
    // could pick a subset of attrs here
    return _.pick(self, _.keys(self))
  }
}
```

Which leaves me free to then populate the `comments` attribute and not have surprises about the data on the wire.